# Trying to add ints from database to a let but always returning NaN

Tags: javascript, mysql, discord.js

I've been trying to get some numbers from a table in my database (MySQL/PHPMyAdmin) and add those to a "let" in the code, but the final outputs are always NaN.

I tried to use the parseInt() function in case the numbers in the table were being treated as strings but without success.

```
var pointsQuery = "SELECT * FROM reacts WHERE userid=" + message.author.id;
con.query(pointsQuery, function (err, rows, fiedls) {
if (err) {
  message.channel.send(err.message);
  throw err;
}
let upvotes = 0;
let downvotes = 0;
for (var i in rows) {
   upvotes = upvotes + parseInt(rows[i].upvotes, 10);
    downvotes = downvotes + parseInt(rows[i].downvotes, 10);
}
upvotes = upvotes - parseInt(rows, 10);
downvotes = downvotes - parseInt(rows, 10);

console.log("up: " + upvotes);
console.log("down:" + downvotes);

let finalPoints = 10 + parseInt((upvotes - (downvotes * 2)), 10);

message.channel.send("<@" + message.author.id + "> has " + finalPoints + " points!");

})
```

The output of both console.log that I used for "debugging" should be a number but is outputting "NaN".
The `final points` should be the result of the expression `10 + (upvotes - (downvotes * 2))`

Comment: if rows is an array, then this will cause your issue: 
`upvotes = upvotes - parseInt(rows, 10);` not sure what that or the next line is meant to do

Comment: Can you try with parseInt(rows[i]); do not write the 10 in it

Comment: @Pete @Deepak Jha, the ```rows``` is an array but when used in the for loop, it seems to work like an int and is used to tell the code how many time it has to do the loop. I assumed that if I parsed ```rows``` it would do the same thing here as it did on the ```for``` loop. I tried to parse ```rows``` without the base (10) but it still outputs NaN.

Comment: In line 13, 14 what is `upvotes = upvotes - parseInt(rows, 10);` and `downvotes = downvotes - parseInt(rows, 10);` supposed to do? you cant parse and array to a number. Add an index just like you did with the loop, maybe you mean `array.Last()`?

Comment: @RenéCarannante, those two lines are meant to subtract the number total of rows got from the sql query. As I said in my last comment, I assumed that if I parsed ```rows``` it would do the same thing here as it did on the ```for``` loop. So, in this case, adding an index or using something like ```array.Last()``` would probably not give me the expected result.

Comment: if you want to subtract the number of total rows you need to specify that you want the length using `array.Length` or `array.Count` depending on your Framework. Also you really should make a variable `let len = parseInt(rows.Length, 10);` to subtract since you do it twince with the same value and you shoulnt waste resources

Comment: @RenéCarannante, that seems to be working. thanks.

Comment: Good to hear I wrote it as answer since some seemed to be interested :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lines 13 and 14 you try to parse and array to an Int which isnt possible. If you want to subtract the number of total rows you need to specify that you want the length using `array.Length` or `array.Count` depending on your Framework. Also you really should make a variable `let len = parseInt(rows.Length, 10);` to subtract since you do it twice with the same value and you shoulnt waste resources
(Reposted answer from comments)

Code:

```
let len = parseInt(rows.Length, 10);
upvotes = upvotes - len;
downvotes = downvotes - len;
```